# Magento 2: how to redirect from an admin controller

Tags: magento2, controllers, redirect, admin-controller

In Magento 1, we were able to do the following directly in a controller action method :

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/index');
```

Or in a more generic way:

```
$this->_redirect('adminhtml/controller/action');
```

What's the equivalent in Magento 2 ?

Comment: Hi Raphael, please create one chat and come to that please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do the following in Magento 2, you must do the following in your `execute` method:

```
public function execute()
{
    /* Do your controller action stuff here */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $resultRedirect->setPath('adminRouteFrontName/controllerFolder/actionClass');
    return $resultRedirect;
}
```

You don't need to add the `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory` to your constructor as it is already declared in the abstract class `Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction` so you have already access to the `$this->resultRedirectFactory` variable.

The parameters in my example are:

- ***adminRouteFrontName***: declared in your `adminhtml/routes.xml`
- ***controllerFolder***: name of the controller folder under `Controller/Adminhtml`
- ***actionClass***: name of your action class under the controller folder for example with `Index.php` it would be `index`, for `Grid.php` it would be `grid` and so on.

You can also still use the `*` as we used to do in M1.

You can also use parameters for example like this:

```
$resultRedirect->setPath('catalog/*/', ['store' => $storeId, '_current' => true, 'id' => $id]);
```

Comment: do you know how I would do this in Javascript?

Answer (score 4):

I just want to add that Your Question and Your answer both are working for me :).
I was searching for a simple method for redirection and accidentally I found that old method (of Mage 1) is still supported on Mage 2, I used the following code to redirect from my custom controller to product grid and it worked :)

```
$this->_redirect('catalog/product/index'); return;
```

I am not sure if it will be supported later or not but it was worth mentioning :)

Comment: Tried in Magento 2.2.4, its working like a charm