# How to redirect form frontController to another module's admin controller in magento2?

Tags: magento2, redirect

I have two modules

1)Paypalrec with action fornt - Index/Index

2) unsubscribe with action admin/Index/UnsubscribeFinal

I want to redirect Index/Index controller to admin/Index/UnsubscribeFinal here.

Can anyone help?

Comment: do you try this solution ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106900/magento-2-how-to-redirect-from-an-admin-controller

Comment: Yes, but it's redirect to me fornt side
http://example.com/unsubscribe/Index/UnsubscribeFinal 

IT should be http://example.com/admin/unsubscribe/Index/UnsubscribeFinal

Answer (score 0):

To do the following in Magento 2, you must do the following in your `execute` method:

```
public function execute()
{
    /* Do your controller action stuff here */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $resultRedirect->setPath('adminRouteFrontName/controllerFolder/actionClass');
    return $resultRedirect;
}
```

You don't need to add the `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory` to your constructor as it is already declared in the abstract class `Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction` so you have already access to the `$this->resultRedirectFactory` variable.

The parameters in my example are:

- ***adminRouteFrontName***: declared in your `adminhtml/routes.xml`
- ***controllerFolder***: name of the controller folder under `Controller/Adminhtml`
- ***actionClass***: name of your action class under the controller folder for example with `Index.php` it would be `index`, for `Grid.php` it would be `grid` and so on.

Comment: i have tried but it's redirect me to front side

Comment: I want redirect front to backend not backend to front